# Can an Ajax script access different website's webpage?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

Can an Ajax script access different website's webpage? for example i tried following

```
xmlhttprequestobj.open("GET","google.com",true);
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot, due to the Same Origin Policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

Your request is valid if the endurl (in your case.. google.com) supports returning data in jsonp format.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access webpages of other domains and hosts, even i tried the same thing you tried, due to security reasons browsers do not allow so.