# HTML mini browser back button disabling

Tags: html, iframe, browser-history

i have the following webpage:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function display(value){
document.getElementById('displayer').src=value;
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="x" onsubmit="return display(this.y.value)">
<input name="y" /><input type="submit" value="display"/>
</form>
<iframe id="displayer">ERROR</iframe>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('displayer').contentWindow.history.back()">Click me to go back in the history of iframe!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and the back button works fine, but when someone reaches the page they started with (in the iframe) and they click the back button it takes them to the previous page they visited in the whole browser window. how can i somehow disable the back button when someone reaches the page they started with?

i can keep track of the page they started with by using the value in the textbox, but how to know which page is currently being visited in the iframe?

if i can know which page is currently being visited in the iframe then i can easily put a conditional statement to disable the button...

i've tried:

`document.getElementById("displayer").contentWindow.location.href`

but it gives me undefined!

i am working on ubuntu 12.10 on google chrome latest version.

please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Answers to **both** questions asked:

*how can i somehow disable the back button when someone reaches the page they started with?*

> You can't.

*how to know which page is currently being visited in the iframe?*

> In this case, there isn't a way.

For security reasons, just like you can't fetch content with AJAX from a source outside your site, you can't get the `iframe` url if outside your site.

Comment: yeah sure i was thinking of a div and ajax loaded content but if they click on a link what happens, the whole page changes to the next page, i want just the div to change its code, how about that?

Comment: You use `AJAX` to get the content and then you place the content into the `div`. A quick example can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787494/jquery-ajax-load-content-into-a-div-when-button-clicked) (jQuery)

Comment: yes i know, but dont you think the whole page will be reloaded when someone clicks a link in the div instead of just the div? or should i put a onclick listener to every link which takes the href value and passes it to the display function which then uses ajax and fetches the new page?

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment as it was probably confusing you. Just think about the example in my previous comment and switch the `<p class="classloader">` used there to `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="classname">`.

Comment: but if i set the old href to javascript:void how will my onclick listener know what the href was? so is there a way of looping through all the `<a>`s in the `div` and changing the href to `javascript:display(oldhref)`

Comment: Look at the example! `$('#contenthere').load('/includes/about-info.html');` <---- it's this

Comment: i am talking about the link in the loaded webpage!

Comment: You must change them all to work this way (if you want to load them in the div).

Comment: but ajax doesn't allow us to get content of other domains due to same origin policy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124152/can-an-ajax-script-access-different-websites-webpage

Comment: Ah, my bad. Wasn't aware you're loading from different site. Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that minimizing the need to navigate using the back button is your best option :/ You can't disable the back button and you can't force the user not to press it. You can just guide the user to use other ways to navigate around your site.

Comment: okay do you know how to get the current url of the iframe, leave out all the rest to me.. read my question all i asked is for getting the url of the iframe...

Comment: See my edited answer. Btw, if you are asking how to get the iframe url, don't set the post title to `HTML mini browser back button disabling`