# Apache PHP mail receiving

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

i have a little PHP script which sends email, which works fine.

But when people send email to my website, i want to display it on my homepage, so I just wanted to know where does my server store the email on my filesystem...

OS: Ubuntu 12.10

Server: Apache2.2 

Mailer: sendmail with PHP

Comment: **How** do people send email to your website?

Comment: by opening their gmail account or something and saying someone@mysite.com but just chuck all that, i just wanna know where does apache and sendmail store mails @budwiser

Comment: This question is about how to setup your email server and does not belong here. You might try taking a look at [How do I set up an email server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54960/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-server)

Comment: no i already have it setup, i just wanna know where does it store mails, is there any path like /var/mail or something where it stores the text messages?

Comment: `/var/mail/user` or `/var/spool/mail/user` are the usual locations according to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/306163/what-is-the-you-have-new-mail-message-in-linux-unix)

Comment: does user refer to the *someone* in someone@mysite.com

Comment: It refers to the _user account_ that the mail alias is bind to.

Comment: okay just a sec i'll try

Comment: okay, thankyou it worked, can you please repost your comment as an answer so that i can accept it please? @budwiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/306163/what-is-the-you-have-new-mail-message-in-linux-unix), in Ubuntu mail is usually stored in

`/var/mail/user`

or

`/var/spool/mail/user`

where the user is the *system user account* that the desired mail alias has been bind to.

Comment: thankyou, just asking out of curiosity, though the mail is successfully send, why does php mail take so long compared to gmail?

Comment: If you're talking about how quickly the mail is transported to the receiver, there's zillions of things affecting that so this question is impossible to answer accurately, especially in a comment :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. However, in the future, please post similar questions to `serverfault.com` as `Stackoverflow` is meant for questions about **programming**.

Comment: okay, could you please try to help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233849/html-mini-browser-back-button-disabling